# Rails: ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor in my rails app. I followed this: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor to implement ckeditor.

So my gemfile contains:

```
   gem "ckeditor"
```

In my routes, i have:

```
  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
```

And I have also created ckeditor model files.

This is my view file:

```
  <%= m.cktext_area :message, :class => "message-body", :placeholder => "Your content", :ckeditor => {:toolbar => "MyToolbar"} %>
```

And my config.js in assets/javascripts/ckeditor is:

```
        CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
        {
          // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
          // config.language = 'fr';
          // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

          /* Filebrowser routes */
          // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
          config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

          // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
          config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

          // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
          config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

          // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
          config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

          // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
          config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

          // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
          config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

          // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
          config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";


          config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
            [
                { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic' ] },
                { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink' ] },
                { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'BulletedList' ] },

            ];
        config.height = '143px';
        config.width = '100%'; 
          // Rails CSRF token
          config.filebrowserParams = function(){
            var csrf_token, csrf_param, meta,
                metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
                params = new Object();

            for ( var i = 0 ; i < metas.length ; i++ ){
              meta = metas[i];

              switch(meta.name) {
                case "csrf-token":
                  csrf_token = meta.content;
                  break;
                case "csrf-param":
                  csrf_param = meta.content;
                  break;
                default:
                  continue;
              }
            }

            if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
              params[csrf_param] = csrf_token;
            }

            return params;
          };

          config.addQueryString = function( url, params ){
            var queryString = [];

            if ( !params ) {
              return url;
            } else {
              for ( var i in params )
                queryString.push( i + "=" + encodeURIComponent( params[ i ] ) );
            }

            return url + ( ( url.indexOf( "?" ) != -1 ) ? "&" : "?" ) + queryString.join( "&" );
          };

          // Integrate Rails CSRF token into file upload dialogs (link, image, attachment and flash)
          CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ){
            // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
            var dialogName = ev.data.name;
            var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
            var content, upload;

            if (CKEDITOR.tools.indexOf(['link', 'image', 'attachment', 'flash'], dialogName) > -1) {
              content = (dialogDefinition.getContents('Upload') || dialogDefinition.getContents('upload'));
              upload = (content == null ? null : content.get('upload'));

              if (upload && upload.filebrowser && upload.filebrowser['params'] === undefined) {
                upload.filebrowser['params'] = config.filebrowserParams();
                upload.action = config.addQueryString(upload.action, upload.filebrowser['params']);
              }
            }
          });
        };
```

But i am getting error of:

```
   ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined[Break On This Error]     

   CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
```

I tried solution available on net but no help.

Can anybody help me out on where i am going wrong??

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it working on changing config.js to this:

```
if (typeof(CKEDITOR) != 'undefined') {
            CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
            {
              config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar'

              config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
                [
                    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic' ] },
                    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink' ] },
                    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image' ] },
                    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'BulletedList' ] },

                ];
            config.height = '143px';
            config.width = '100%'; 
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
   config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
   config.autoParagraph = false;
  }
}
```